# Displaying multiple images in jsp using a struts2 iterator

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

i am working on a little web application where i am facing a problem. Here, i have a list of contents which i am displaying in a jsp page using an iterator. For each content there can be some images associated with it. I want to display those images along with the contents. How this can be achieved.

Here is say my content iterator.

```
<s:iterator value="contentList">
     <s:property value="id"/>
     <s:property value="topic"/>
```

Now within this iterator tag, i want to generate a second iterator dynamically with the "id" attribute of the first iterator. I have a database table of images mapped to each content by the "id" attribute. I want to get the list of images associated with that particular content and then display them in the jsp page. The images can be multiple. How can this be achieved. Please help.

The images are stored in file system, with the paths stored in database. For displaying a single image, what i am doing is that, i get the image path from the database in the action class and then pass the image by a fileInputStream to the jsp page. The problem arises when i try to display multiple images.

Code used for displaying the image in jsp

```
<img src="contentimage.action?contentID=<s:property value="id"/>"/>
```

The `<s:property value="id"/>` is the value available with the content iterator.

And in action class

```
Image ImageObject=cd.getImageObject(contentID);
File file = new  File(ImageObject.getFilePath()+"/"+ImageObject.getFileName());         
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

The `Image` is a Bean class having image attributes, like FilePath in the file system, image file name etc. 
Now, for a given `contentID`, there can be multiple images in the database, all with diffrent filename and filepath. I can get them in a list of `Image` type. Now how to iterate over them in jsp page and display the images of those paths. Hope, i am making my question clear this time.

**EDIT**

My Content Class which is mapped to Hibernate.

```
private int id;
private String topic;
//getters and Setters
```

My ContentImage class which is mapped to Hibernate.

```
private int contentId; // this is the id of the Content class
private String fileName; //image file name
private String filePath; // image file path, actual file is stored in file system
private String imageByte; //Base64 string of the image file
//getters and setters
```

Now, in the action class prior to loading the view jsp, i get the Content List.

```
contentList=//got the list here;
```

Now displaying it in the jsp using an iterator.

```
<s:iterator value="contentList">
   <s:property value="id"/>
   <s:property value="topic"/>
   Now here i want a second iterator of my ContentImage class having a list of images corresponding to the id value of the contentList iterator.
   //This is where i am having the problem. I can display single image with this:
  <img src="contentimage.action?contentID=<s:property value="id"/>"/> //But i need to display all the images associated with this id.

   So i need an iterator created dynamically here with the id attribute and then display the images. Like:
   <s:iterator value="contentImageList">
      <img src="displayimage.action?filepath=<s:property value="filePath"/>"/>
   </s:iterator>
  </s:iterator>
```

I am not being able to create the second iterator.Please help me in this.

Comment: I can display a single image by passing an action with the "id" attribute in the "src" field of the "img" tag. But there are multiple images. How can i display all of them with the same "img" tag or iterate with them?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you're asking. Can you provide your bean to help us understand?

Comment: Place the `img` tag inside the iterator.

Comment: Edited the question and added more information @Andrea Ligios

Comment: Can you change your `Content` class and add list of `ContentImage` to it?

Comment: I have tried that @Aleksandr M. Then hibernate gives an error, as the database can not create a column "ContentImage" for my Content table  with attribute List

Comment: What error do you get? Have you used `@OneToMany` annotation?

Comment: This problem has been solved. Thanks for all your responses. I used OneToMany annotation as suggested by @AleksandrM and inserted the ContentImage list inside the COntent class. Then displayed it using a second iterator for ContentImageList inside the contentList Iteraror as suggested by AndreaLigios. Face dthe problem of Lazy initialize exception and solved it using EAGER Fetch. Is it a good solution. Can it be improved further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of variables here: are the images in the database, or in a File System and only the path / URI is in the database ? How do you display them on page ? [Base64 data-URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) (*ouch* for no caching)? How do you load them ? In the Action before the page is loaded, or in the iteration with for example `<s:action />` tag ?

Assuming a base scenario where you have an object with simple properties and a `List<String>` containing the Base64 converted images (with Apache Commons's [encodeBase64URLSafeString](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#line.591)) from the byte arrays:

```
class Row {
    private Long id;
    private String topic;
    private List<String> images;
    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */
}
```

and you load a List of these objects in the action, before reaching the view:

```
private List<Row> rows;

/* GETTER AND SETTER */

public String execute(){
    rows = loadRowsInSomeWay();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

then in JSP you could draw them like this:

```
<s:iterator value="rows">
     <s:property value="id"/>
     <s:property value="topic"/>

     <s:iterator value="images">
         <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<s:property/>"/>
     </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

**EDIT**

Assuming what you have already works for one image, and that you have a structure like above, with some properties and a list of String (or Long, or whatever) called "images" containing the `id` of the images:

```
<s:iterator value="rows">
     <s:property value="id"/>
     <s:property value="topic"/>

     <s:iterator value="images">
         <img src="contentimage.action?contentID=<s:property />"/>             
     </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have edited the question to provide more information. I will try your solution. I have not used Base64 method for displaying image till now. I will try it.

Comment: I have tried the Base64 encoding method and the image display is working. If i go by your example, i have a Row class with some attributes. I can not create a List<String> attribute there as the class is mapped to hibernate and the database can not create a table column with a List parameter. What i have done is, created another Bean class say Images with attributes "RowId" that is mapped to the "id" of the Row class(like foreign key) and other necessary image attributes. Now how can i get this list in one iterator and display the list inside the other iterator "rows"

Comment: Can't you simply post the relevant parts of your code ? It's hard to guess the missing pieces :/ Btw you can nest iterators like above, is not enough for your case ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved the problem using your solution. Details are mentioned in the comments of my post. Thanks again.