# Struts2 Result type for Image

Tags: struts2, tags

In Struts2 Application I tried to have my Custome Result Type. but am getting no Effect, My JSP page image based action is not getting called.And No Exception am getting also.Please correct me where am doing wrong.
HTTPFox says 404 but am not getting anything in JAVA Console.

**HTML :**

```
 <img src=" <s:url action='ExternalImageAction' />" />
```

**XML :**

```
<package name="externalImage_package" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="myBytesResult" class="leo.struts.CustomeImageResult" />
        </result-types>

        <action name="ExternalImageAction" class="leo.struts.ExternalImageAction">
            <result name="myImageResult" type="myBytesResult">
            </result>
        </action>
</package>
```

**HTTPFOX :**

```
00:18:06.762    0.044   432 1258    GET 404 text/html (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)    http://localhost:8888/Struts2Whole/%3Cs:url%20action=%27ExternalImageAction%27%20/%3E
```

**CustomeImageResult:**

public void execute(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

```
ExternalImageAction action = (ExternalImageAction) invocation.getAction();
HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();

response.setContentType(action.getContentType());       
response.getOutputStream().write(action.getImageInBytes());
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

}

**ExternalImageAction :**

```
public String execute()
{
    System.out.println("execute of the ExternalImageAction...........");
    setContentType("jpg");
    setImageInBytes(getFileBytes("C:/Users/Joseph.M/Desktop/ocwcd5.jpg"));
    return "myImageResult";
}
public static  byte[] getFileBytes(String filePath)
{
    File file = new File(filePath);

    System.out.println("file : "+file.getName());
    byte[] b = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try {
          FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
          fileInputStream.read(b);
          for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                      System.out.print((char)b[i]);
           }
          fileInputStream.close();
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 System.out.println("File Not Found.");
                 e.printStackTrace();
     }
     catch (IOException e1) {
              System.out.println("Error Reading The File.");
               e1.printStackTrace();
     }        
    System.out.println("byes of image size : "+b.length);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Post a code for `CustomeImageResult`.

Comment: Hi @RomanC pls check the updated code.Thnaks for reply.

Comment: Did you use JSP taglib directive before using struts tag?

Comment: There are a number of things wrong here, including the content type, using the bytes of a JPG as an image URL, the content type, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you return something to the `src` attribute of an `<img />` tag, it thinks it is an URL, try to open it and receives `404 Not Found`.

Since you are not returning an URL, but the actual image in a byte array, you need to use a [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) as defined in [RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397).

Assuming your result only return the bytes, you should put the Data URI in the html, like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20019398/1654265

Otherwise, you could return the complete Data URI (that must include the Mime Type) in the struts result itself, and keeping your current JSP unchanged.

Simply turn the `byte[]` to a Base64 String with Apache Commons's `encodeBase64URLSafeString`, append it to a String like `data:image/jpeg;base64,` and return that.